# how to check if atleast one checkbox is checked android

Tags: java, android

This what I have done so far, even though I check all of them I get AlertDialog message.

```
  private void validateCheckBoxes() {

    if (toilets.isSelected() || wifi.isSelected() || trolleys.isSelected() || lifts.isSelected()
            && ticketMachine.isSelected() || stepFree.isSelected()) {
        saveRecordsToDatabase();


    } else {
        AlertDialog.Builder facilitiesError = new AlertDialog.Builder(AddStation.this);
        facilitiesError.setTitle("Station Facilities are not selected");
        facilitiesError.setMessage("Please select at least one facility ");

        facilitiesError.setNegativeButton("OK", null);
        facilitiesError.create().show();

    }

}
```

Comment: I have tried it before. It doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By "selected" do you mean "checked"?

```
if (toilets.isChecked() || wifi.isChecked() || trolleys.isChecked() || lifts.isChecked()
    || ticketMachine.isChecked() || stepFree.isChecked()) {
    saveRecordsToDatabase();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

modify your code:

```
if (toilets.isSelected() || wifi.isSelected() || trolleys.isSelected() || lifts.isSelected()
        || ticketMachine.isSelected() || stepFree.isSelected()) {
    saveRecordsToDatabase();
}
```

Explanation: you are using all && operators in if statement, which means you get alert message only if all the check boxes are checked.

If you use all || (or) operator, it means you get alert message if at least one checkbox is checked.

Comment: Please explain your answer. Why should this work, what did you change? Remember, OP wouldn't have asked if they already knew.

Comment: its isChecked not is isSelected